# NPM does not install Bitbucket URL dependency with SSH Key

Tags: git, bitbucket, npm-install, ssh-keys

I am trying to add a bitbucket url as module dependency.I already setup ssh key and its already working when using git clone but when adding a url dependency during npm install it still asking for username and password.

```
dependencies: { 
    test-module: git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git#v1.0.0
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that url formatted correctly? I know that `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` works. I'm not sure how `git+ssh://` is interpreted, but it seems to me like the `:username` part of it would be interpreted as a port number.

Comment: HI yes I followed format here.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json.
Also added Identity in .ssh but npm still asking for username and password. Am i missing a config in npm? Thanks